# What would be an example of characters forming a complete, orthogonal basis for class functions?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I understand characters are traces of the matrix of a representation $D(g): G \rightarrow GL(V)$ in representations, but I really fail to understand how these functions can form a basis for the class functions. From how I see it, they are nothing but numbers.

Perhaps someone could shed light on this problem for me by giving an example, maybe on the $S_3$ representation or something, please? Thank you!

Comment: $g\mapsto tr D(g)$ is surely a function from $G$ to $\Bbb{C}$ (assuming complex reps for now). It is even a class function, do you see why?

Comment: @D.Tran : I deleted my comment, I just understood that $D : G \to GL(V)$ was the representation, sorry about this.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. I see the character is a class function. But I don't know why they form a basis for other class functions, or even the characters of a different representation...

Comment: What would a basis for the space of class functions be, if not "nothing but numbers"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm They even say that the characters forming an orthogonal basis... Yet I see characters having the same value, across both row (representation) and column (class) of the character table...
$$$$

I mean, if a basis for class functions is as simple a number, then it'd be too obvious since class functions map to $\mathbb{C}$ (am I correct)? Then every class function can be reach by another class function by simply multiplying by a complex number? Is that all this is about?

Comment: @D.Tran: It's not each of the number that's a basis for the class functions, it's all the numbers that make up all of the characters _together_ that become a basis for the space of class functions. Do you understand that each character is a class function? Do you understand that all class functions taken together form a vector space?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not really on the last question; I don't see how the class functions can form a basis. For example in $S_3$ under trivial representation, they have 3 number $1$... and that was supposed to form a basis for what? Alternating and Standard representations? Which are also numbers like $1$, $-1$, etc.? I only need one character to form a basis then... I just don't get it...

Comment: @D.Tran: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are a class functions, then $x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)$ is also a class function, and if $\lambda$ is any complex number, then $x\mapsto \lambda f(x)$ is also a class function. These operations makes the set of class functions into a complex vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S_3$ we have
$$ \begin{array}{l|ccc|ccc}
g\in S_3 & \chi_1(g) & \chi_2(g) & \chi_3(g) & f_1(g) & f_3(g) & f_3(g) \\ \hline
e & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ %\hline
(12) & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
(23) & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
(13) & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ %\hline
(123) & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
(132) & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array} $$
which shows the three irreducible characters $\chi_1$, $\chi_2$, $\chi_3$ and three other class functions $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$.

It should be clear that $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ are a basis for the space of all class functions, so this space has dimension $3$. One can also check that $\{\chi_1,\chi_2,\chi_3\}$ are linearly independent, and since there are just as many $\chi_i$s as there are $f_i$, the $\chi_i$s must be a basis too.

And you can compute directly that every pair of different $\chi_i$s are orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 2):

So we fix a finite group $G$. Let $D : G \to GL(V)$ be a representation where $V$ is a complex finite dimensional vector space. We notice that $\operatorname{tr}(D(ghg^{-1})) = \operatorname{tr}(D(h))$, so to any representation $D$ on a finite dimensional vector space, we obtain a class functions, that is a function $f : G \to \Bbb C$ so that if $g$ and $g'$ are conjugated then $f(g) = f(g')$.

Now as you suggested we will work the $S_3$ example.

First, the conjugacy classes in $S_3$ are $e, (12)$ and $(123)$. We write these classes $c_0,c_1$ and $c_2$. A function invariant under conjugaison can be written as $\lambda c_0 + \mu c_1 + \delta c_2$ where the greek letters are complex numbers.

Now, we have three irreducible representations : the trivial representation $\rho_0$, the representation $\rho_1$ which is the sign representation. Finally there is a third representation, given on $\Bbb C^2$ seen as $\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb C^3 : x + y + z = 0 \}$.

For example, the trace of $\rho_0$ is just the function equal to $1$, that is $c_0 + c_1 + c_2$. The sign representation has trace $1$ on $e$ and $(123)$ and $-1$ on $(12)$ so the function is $c_0 - c_1 + c_2$.

As an exercise, you can compute the trace for the third representation and verify that the three functions you obtained are linearly independant.

Edit : In the vector space of class functions (i.e conjugaison invariant functions $\phi : G \to \Bbb C$), there is a natural product given by $\langle \phi_1, \phi_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \phi_1(g)\overline{\phi_2}(g)$. The orthogonality relations says that if $\chi_1, \chi_2$ are the trace functions of irreducible representations $V_1,V_2$, then $\langle, \chi_1, \chi_2\rangle = 1$ if $V_1 \cong V_2$ and $0$ else.

For example, $\langle \rho_0, \rho_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{6} (1 - 3 + 2) = 0$ and $\langle \rho_0, \rho_0 \rangle = \frac{1}{6} (1 + 3 + 2) = 1$.

Comment: So I actually overcomplicated thing! Thank you!

Comment: @D.Tran : You're welcome :-)

Comment: Wait, one last thing I wanna ask: they also say that this basis is "orthonormal". Or in Georgi's book Lie Algebras in Particle Physics: "The characters are also different for each inequivalent irred representatons.". What does this mean? When I look at the character table of $S_3$, I see similar value of $(123)$ in the trivial $(1)$ and alternating $(2)$ representation...

Comment: @D.Tran : I explained the orthonormality. For the second part, is means that $V_1 \cong V_2$ iff the characters are equal _as functions_. Of course, two functions can be different but still agree for some values.

Comment: \operatorname{tr} and \text{tr} do not yield identical results in all cases. Look at the contrast between 3\operatorname{tr}A and 3\text{tr}A: $3\operatorname{tr}A,$ $3\text{tr}A.$ Or between 3\operatorname{tr}(A) and 3\text{tr}(A): $3\operatorname{tr}(A),$ $3\text{tr}(A). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy : thank you for the edit and your comment !

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet : I added a bit to the comment after you commented. What I added shows you the context-dependent nature of the spacing.